# What do the details on bfgminer mean

Tags: bfgminer

What do the details mean on `bfgminer`?

Like at the bottom of the command prompt, before the devices show up, it has:

```
A:8781 R:11+0(.14%) HW:5527/ 37%
```

What does that all mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Each column is as follows:
  The number of devices and processors currently mining
  Hottest temperature reported by any processor
  5 second exponentially decaying average hash rate
  An all time average hash rate
  An all time average hash rate based on actual nonces found, adjusted for pool
      reject and stale rate
  The number of Accepted shares
  The number of Rejected shares and stale shares discarded (never submitted),
      and the percentage these are of total found.
  The number of HardWare errors, and percentage invalid of nonces returned
```